# Issues trying to display mentionable roles

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Hi I'm having an issue trying to display a symbol that denotes a role that can be mentioned in Discord. I'm currently using discord.py and they use `role.mentionable` which is a Boolean https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.Role.mentionable

What I'm trying to accomplish and failing to do is being able to set add :bell: in front of the role that is mentionable while :nobell: for the roles that are not.

I get the error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'mentionable'`

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
@commands.command(pass_context=True, no_pm=True, name='list', aliases=['roles', 'role'])
async def _list(self, ctx):
    """List of all available roles """
    guild = ctx.message.guild
    author = ctx.message.author
    botroom = self.bot.get_channel(555844758778544160) 
    intros = self.bot.get_channel(485381365366390796)
     #--- Role list Categories ---"


    if ctx.message.channel == intros:
        pass
    else:
        if ctx.message.channel == botroom:
            title = '**Hey {}, here is a categorised list of roles you can add:**'.format(author.display_name)
            embed = discord.Embed(title=title.format(), colour=0x0080c0)
            embed.add_field(name="\n**__Notifications__**", value="roles with a :bell: at the beginning of them are @mentionable - when applied you may recieve notifications.\n\n", inline=False)
            embed.set_footer(text="Tip: to add a role from the list type the command !add/remove followed by the role.")

            #Lets start embed roles list below#

            #Colours
            Colours = ['Blue', 'Green', 'Orange', 'Yellow', 'Pink', 'Purple']
            Colours.sort(key=str.lower)
            embed.add_field(name='**__Colour Roles__**', value='\n'.join([":bell: {} **({})**" if role.mentionable in Colours else ":no_bell: {} **({})**".format(role, len([member for member in guild.members if ([r for r in member.roles if r.name == role])])) for role in Colours]))


            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        else:
            await ctx.send('You can only use this command in {}.'.format(botroom.mention))
```

More specifically the error is on this line within the code

```
 embed.add_field(name='**__Colour Roles__**', value='\n'.join([":bell: {} **({})**" if role.mentionable in Colours else ":no_bell: {} **({})**".format(role, len([member for member in guild.members if ([r for r in member.roles if r.name == role])])) for role in Colours]))
```

I'm not sure what to do from here.
Help much appreciated.

**Edit: reply @Kanasaki Torisowa**

```
Colours = ['Blue', 'Green', 'Orange', 'Yellow', 'Pink', 'Purple']
            Colours.sort(key=str.lower)
            for role in guild.roles:
                if role.mentionable in Colours == True:
                    embed.add_field(name='**__Colour Roles__**', value='\n'.join(["{} **({})**".format(role, len([member for member in guild.members if ([r for r in member.roles if r.name == role])])) for role in Colours]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the emoji icon by adding a forward slash in-front of the emoji like this `\:no_bell:` or `\:bell:`

```py
@command()
async def mentionable_roles(self, msg):
    channel = self.bot.get_channel(555844758778544160)
    if msg.channel == channel:  # channel is equal to  `555844758778544160`
        emb = discord.Embed(title='Server Roles')  # set the embed title
        for i in msg.guild.roles:  # loop through the roles
            print(i.colour)
            if i.mentionable == True:  # role is mentionable
                # add bell icon since role is mentionable
                emb.add_field(name=i.name, value='')

            if i.mentionable == False:  # role is not mentionable
                # add no bell icon since role is not mentionable
                emb.add_field(name=i.name, value='')

        emb.set_footer(
            text="Tip: to add a role from the list type the command !add/remove followed by the role.")
        await msg.send(embed=emb)
    if msg.channel != channel:
        await msg.send(f"You can only use this command at {channel.name}")
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm unsure how to adapt this in to my current code. But I've added an extension on to my question to show you what I have tried.

Comment: @James, I'm not a bit confused, but I've edited it to the answer to best match what you're trying to do from what I understand.

Comment: This is good thank you for your answer. However,  this method I can't keep my roles in to categories. In my answer you'll see that my roles are in individual categories which is what I'd like to keep while assigning the roles that are mentionable/unmentionable in their categories with a `value=''` or `value=''`